# how can I install Qt Designer for PyQt5 for WINDOWS 10

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, pypi

how can I install Qt Designer for PyQt5.
I installed SIP from PyPi by running: 
    pip3 install SIP
and I installed PyQt5 also from PyPi by running: 
    pip3 install PyQt5
but I didn't find QT Designer

Comment: I downloaded the package but I don't know how to instal it?,

Comment: problem solve thank you

Answer (score 1):

Qt designer doesn't come bundled with PyQt5. You can install it separately using `pip install pyqt5-tools` (or `pip3 install pyqt5-tools`).

You will find designer.exe at:
`...\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5_tools\Qt\bin`